# Which kinds of closures for spice and herb containers exist and what are their advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: spices, storage

I have an extensive collection of spices and dried herbs, which I store currently in apothecary bottles with a cork stopper.

Most websites that deal with closure types focus on the differences for beverages, especially wine. Considering the requirements for storing spices and dried herbs (protection from humidity, flavor-retaining, pest control and prevention of contamination by the storage container itself due to industrial binding agents within cork or PVC plasticizers), is a cork stopper the solution with the most benefits?

Comment: Small mason jars seem to be the ideal container, with a large enough opening to be able to use a spoon to take spice/herb.

Comment: @Max : You just need better spoons : https://www.amazon.com/Depot-Premium-Stainless-Measuring-Spoons/dp/B018F9YGRA  .  And cork actually sounds like a good idea, as it would help regulate moisture in the container (so long as you didn't leave stuff in there for so long that it went stale)

Answer (score 1):

The only truly, definitely airtight seals widely available are either plastic snap locks with a gasket, or bail-lock type glass containers.

Mind that there are a few spices (clove powder and mixtures containing it) that can be surprisingly aggressive towards plastics.